# powershell script restart services on 100s computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need to restart the services on hundreds sometimes less depending on if backup jobs failed on the remote machine with

```
$services = "winmgmt", "cryptsvc", "vss"
$computers = get-content "${env:\userprofile}\servers.txt"
foreach ($srv in $ computers) {
get-service -computername $srv $services | restart-service -force
}
```

while this works, it does not do it asynchronously, only one at a time, is there a way I can send the job out to all the machines at once?

Comment: invoke-command comp1,comp2,comp3 runs in parallel.

Comment: @js2010 I did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Invoke-Command to run the command as a Job, you can then wait for all the jobs to complete, something like this should do it.

```
$computers = get-content "${env:\userprofile}\servers.txt"
$sb = {
    $services = "winmgmt", "cryptsvc", "vss"
    get-service -Name $services | Restart-Service -PassThru | Get-Service
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $sb
```

Comment: Nice. `Invoke-Command` also accepts multiple computer names at once, so you could do `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $sb -AsJob |Wait-Job |Receive-Job`

Comment: Even better, thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I have updated

Comment: thanks. is there a way to verify if the services were restarted?

Comment: You can use Restart-Service with Passthru and pipe it back into get-service to ensure the service is running again (Restart-Service -PassThru | Get-Service)

Comment: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $sb -AsJob |Wait-Job |Receive-Job ..... what does receive-job do?

Comment: seems like the job is stuck with no feedback

Comment: when i ran the script, i think it tried to restart all services on the machine. instead of those 3 i mentioned. why is that?

Comment: I have updated the answer based on feedback from @js2010 and added another get-service so you can see the current state

Comment: Services need to be inside scritpblock

Comment: Hi, I tried this script and it works. But is it possible to get some verbose feedback while the job is running?

Answer (score 0):

Demo of invoke-command running in parallel:

```
# elevated prompt
measure-command { 
  invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { sleep 5 } } | 
  % seconds

5
```